# Re-render component with an addition Grid Row

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid

I'm getting an object of messages through an API call and update the state with the message property in the object. I'm using the grid in material-ui to display these incoming messages. From what I can deduce you have to hard code the grid space before rendering like this:

```
 <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
```

I want it so that every time I get information from the API call, the component adds a row in the grid and displays the information there. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using your api call responce list:

```
const PaperList = [
  {
    key: 'Paper 1'
  },
  {
    key: 'Paper 2'
  },
  {
    key: 'Paper 3'
  },
  {
    key: 'Paper 4'
  }
];

<div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        {PaperList.map(value => (
          <Grid item key={value.key} style={{ width: '33.333%' }}>
            <Paper key={value.key} className={classes.paper}>{value.key}</Paper>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </div>
```